# Show query result column types (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, psql

Is there a way to easily get the column types of a query result?  I read the psql documentation, but I don't think it supports that.  Ideally, I'd be able to get something like:

```
 columna : text | columnb : integer
----------------+-------------------
 oh hai         |                42
```

Is there a way I can get this information without coding something up?

Comment: Ha, I just asked this question yesterday in #postgresql (no answer then)

Comment: I don't think the `psql` can show it to you directly. But it should be fairly easy to modify it to do so. Perhaps you could write a stored procedure to emulate this though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can print exactly what you have in the sample, unless you write a stored procedure for it.

One way to do it (two "selects"):

1. `create table my_table as select ...`
2. `\d my_table`
3. `select * from my_table`

Comment: Yeah, I just needed the types, not necessarily that format.  Thanks.

Comment: This seems rather kludgy and inconvenient compared to using `pg_typeof()`.

Comment: @JayTaylor I agree. Life is a journey. :-)

Answer (score 63):

It is possible to get any SELECT query result column type.

**Example**

Given the following query and result, let's answer the question *"What is the column type of all_ids?"*

```
SELECT array_agg(distinct "id") "all_ids" FROM "auth_user";

                 all_ids
--------------------------------------------
 {30,461577687337538580,471090357619135524}
(1 row)
```

We need a mechanism to unveil the type of "all_ids".

On the [postgres mailing list archives](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Show-type-in-psql-SELECT-td5746350.html) I found reference to a native pg function called **`pg_typeof`**.

Example usage:

```
SELECT pg_typeof(array_agg(distinct "id")) "all_ids" FROM "auth_user";
```

Output:

```
 all_ids
----------
 bigint[]
(1 row)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 16):

It is definitely possible with `\gdesc` command(psql 11):

> **[\gdesc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-psql.html)**
>
> **Shows the description (that is, the column names and data types) of the result of the current query buffer. The query is not actually
> executed;** however, if it contains some type of syntax error, that
> error will be reported in the normal way.
>
> If the current query buffer is empty, the most recently sent query is described instead.

For example:

```
$ SELECT * FROM pg_database \gdesc

    COLUMN     |   TYPE    
---------------+-----------
 datname       | name
 datdba        | oid
 encoding      | INTEGER
 datcollate    | name
 datctype      | name
 datistemplate | BOOLEAN
 datallowconn  | BOOLEAN
 datconnlimit  | INTEGER
 datlastsysoid | oid
 datfrozenxid  | xid
 datminmxid    | xid
 dattablespace | oid
 datacl        | aclitem[]
```

Comment: Does anything as convenient exist in postgres/psql 10?

Comment: @JustinBailey Unfortunately, I didn't find nice equivalent for psql 10.

Comment: you can use later version `psql` to access older PostgreSQL server, e.g. `apt install postgresql-client-11`