# How to get a list column names and datatypes of a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

How can I get a list of column names and datatypes of a table in PostgreSQL using a query?

Comment: [plsql \gdesc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53964639/5070879) is also an option. The neat feature is it could describe entire queries(useful for complex adhoc ones) but it works for simplified scenario  `SELECT * FROM tab_name \gdesc` as well.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
SELECT
        a.attname as "Column",
        pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) as "Datatype"
    FROM
        pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
    WHERE
        a.attnum > 0
        AND NOT a.attisdropped
        AND a.attrelid = (
            SELECT c.oid
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
                LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
            WHERE c.relname ~ '^(hello world)$'
                AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
        );
```

[image: Change the hello world with your table name]

More info on it : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html

Comment: Works, but why are you using `c.relname ~ '^(hello world)$` instead of simply `c.relname = 'hello world'`?

Answer (score 274):

```
SELECT
    column_name,
    data_type
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    table_name = 'table_name';
```

with the above query you can retrieve columns and its datatype.

Comment: That won't give the right answer for user-defined types (e.g., Geometry and Geography columns created by *ogr2ogr*, which are of the form `geometry(Geometry,[SRID])`).

Comment: One might also use `table_catalog = 'my_database'` and `table_schema = 'my_schema'` in order to get only columns from a specific table of a specific schema of a specific database.

Comment: May I suggest to everyone, if you are looking to build on this code. Use the `pg_catalog` and not the `information_schema`. The `information_schema` has some pretty easy and universal SQL, however it is slower because it is higher level.

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch however, `pg_catalog` is subject to breaking changes between postgres versions.

Comment: @MarcoMannes or `table_schema = current_schema()`. For postgres the `information_schema` only contains data for the current database, so you don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 235):

Open `psql` command line and type :

```
\d+ table_name
```

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't the most upvoted answer.

Comment: This is incomplete as OP may want to do this programmatically in SQL code, not just via psql.

Comment: Postgres does it programmatically, so just start postgres with the '-E' flag: `psql -E` and for every backslash command the respective SQL will be displayed before the result of the command.

Comment: Presuming OP has access to `psql` makes this answer a little out of scope.  Having postgres does not presume proficiency or the ability to access `psql`.

Comment: I was initially dismissive of this answer, but surprisingly, this worked out the best for me when creating a dblink. I just copied and pasted the output into a spreadsheet, split by | got the first two columns, added a comma column and a ); at the end and we have a dblink query.

Answer (score 26):

Don't forget to add the schema name in case you have multiple schemas with the same table names.

```
SELECT column_name, data_type 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'your_table_name' AND table_schema = 'your_schema_name';
```

or using psql:

```
\d+ your_schema_name.your_table_name
```

Answer (score 24):

A version that supports finding the column names and types of a table in a specific schema, and uses JOINs without any subqueries

```sql
SELECT
    pg_attribute.attname AS column_name,
    pg_catalog.format_type(pg_attribute.atttypid, pg_attribute.atttypmod) AS data_type
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_attribute
INNER JOIN
    pg_catalog.pg_class ON pg_class.oid = pg_attribute.attrelid
INNER JOIN
    pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
WHERE
    pg_attribute.attnum > 0
    AND NOT pg_attribute.attisdropped
    AND pg_namespace.nspname = 'my_schema'
    AND pg_class.relname = 'my_table'
ORDER BY
    attnum ASC;
```

Comment: This is my favorite answer because it accomplishes 2 things. It uses the `pg_catalog` and it forces you specify the schema. If you are cramming everything thing in the public schema, I personally believe that is a bad strategy. As your project grows, it will be difficult to keep things organized. IMHO

Answer (score 9):

Updated Pratik answer to support more schemas and nullables:

```
SELECT
    "pg_attribute".attname                                                    as "Column",
    pg_catalog.format_type("pg_attribute".atttypid, "pg_attribute".atttypmod) as "Datatype",

    not("pg_attribute".attnotnull) AS "Nullable"
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_attribute "pg_attribute"
WHERE
    "pg_attribute".attnum > 0
    AND NOT "pg_attribute".attisdropped
    AND "pg_attribute".attrelid = (
        SELECT "pg_class".oid
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_class "pg_class"
            LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace "pg_namespace" ON "pg_namespace".oid = "pg_class".relnamespace
        WHERE
            "pg_namespace".nspname = 'schema'
            AND "pg_class".relname = 'table'
    );
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT column_name,data_type 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE
table_name = 'your_table_name' 
AND table_catalog = 'your_database_name' 
AND table_schema = 'your_schema_name';
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

```
 --how to get a list column names and datatypes of a table in PostgreSQL?


    SELECT DISTINCT
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY pgc.relname , a.attnum) as rowid , 
        pgc.relname as table_name ,
        a.attnum as attr,
        a.attname as name,
        format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) as typ,
        a.attnotnull as notnull, 
        com.description as comment,
        coalesce(i.indisprimary,false) as primary_key,
        def.adsrc as default
    FROM pg_attribute a 
    JOIN pg_class pgc ON pgc.oid = a.attrelid
    LEFT JOIN pg_index i ON 
        (pgc.oid = i.indrelid AND i.indkey[0] = a.attnum)
    LEFT JOIN pg_description com on 
        (pgc.oid = com.objoid AND a.attnum = com.objsubid)
    LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef def ON 
        (a.attrelid = def.adrelid AND a.attnum = def.adnum)
    LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = pgc.relnamespace

    WHERE 1=1 
        AND pgc.relkind IN ('r','')
        AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
        AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
        AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'

    AND a.attnum > 0 AND pgc.oid = a.attrelid
    AND pg_table_is_visible(pgc.oid)
    AND NOT a.attisdropped
    ORDER BY rowid
    ;
```

Comment: Please include context with your code. Also, how do you expand this to other schemas?

Answer (score 3):

To make this topic 'more complete'.

I required the column names and data types on a SELECT statement (not a table).

If you want to do this on a SELECT statement instead of an actual existing table, you can do the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS abc;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE abc AS
-- your select statement here!
SELECT 
    *
FROM foo
-- end your select statement
;

select column_name, data_type 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'abc';
DROP IF EXISTS abc;
```

Short explanation, it makes a (temp) table of your select statement, which you can 'call' upon via the query provided by (among others) @a_horse_with_no_name and @selva.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a way to get column names with data types without PSQL cl, directly from pgAdmin 4, and found a workaround. Adding one more option:

right-click desired database > generate ERD(Beta) > Generate SQL(or Alt+Ctrl+S) and pgAdmin 4 will open Query Editor where you can find all tables with column names and data types:
[image: Query Editor]

Answer (score 2):

without mentioning schema also you can get the required details 
Try this query->

select column_name,data_type 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'table_name';

Answer (score 1):

```
query = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'schema_name' AND table_name = 'table_name'"
qry = execute(query)
print(qry)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34641044)

Comment: @XMehdi01: Why doesn’t it answer the question? It looks like an answer to me. Is this due to a technical issue? E.g., do you believe the answer is incorrect? Because, otherwise, it’s still proposing a solution.

Comment: That said, @kamran-kausar, this would be a much more valuable answer if you explained how your approach is different from the validated answers, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient. Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Below will list all the distinct data types of all the table in the provided schema name.

```
\copy (select distinct data_type, column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name in (SELECT tablename FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE schemaname != 'pg_catalog' AND schemaname != 'information_schema' and schemaname = '<Your schema name>')) to 'datatypes.csv'  delimiter as ',' CSV header
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new function to get the table info

```
CREATE FUNCTION xdesc(in t varchar) RETURNS table(column_name varchar, 
data_type varchar) AS $$
  SELECT column_name, data_type 
  FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = $1 
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;


select xdesc('rs_rail_job_index')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found @Pratik's answer to be the thing, but it didn't work for me for some reason. I've rewritten it in a more consise, if I may, manner. It's easier to understand, it supports schemas and actually works for me (`postgres 15`). **No joins**.

```
SELECT
    attname AS colname,
    pg_catalog.format_type(atttypid, atttypmod) AS coltype
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_attribute
WHERE
    attnum > 0 AND
    NOT attisdropped AND
    attrelid = 'your table name'::regclass
ORDER BY
    attnum ASC
;
```

*P.S.* It also supports composite types (which I actually needed very much). It would return a string like this: `schemaname.tablename`.