# Recover table name in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I think it's a stupid question but is it possible to recover tables names for each columns in a SQL Query ? Example if my query is:

```
Select e.empno,e.sal,d.deptno
FROM emp e JOIN dept d
ON e.deptno = d.deptno
WHERE e.job = 'Analyst'
```

I would like to recover something like this

```
+-------+---------+
| Column|  Table  |
+-------+---------+
|  empno| emp     |
|   sal | emp     |
| deptno| dept    | 
+-------+---------+
```

I use postgresql

Thank for help

Comment: yes.  System tables contain this information but vary by database engine.  So what database are you using Oracle, mySQL, SQL Server Other?  `Select column_name, Table_name from SystemTables (ALL_TAB_COLS [oracle] INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS [mySQL] where tableName in ('EMP,' 'DEPT')`

Comment: I use postgresql, I will try this solution

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194806/how-to-get-a-list-column-names-and-datatype-of-a-table-in-postgresql

Comment: Having selected @xQbert's link, I don't consider this to be a duplicate.

Comment: The JDBC driver returns this information through `ResultSetMetaData.getTableName()` maybe you can use that?

Answer (score 1):

When a result is set back to the client it comes without any display or formatting. I assume this question from the context of PSQL in which case you're not referring to actually getting the column names of the table, but instead to the display-format of the query result. PSQL calls this *expanded display*. You can enable it with `\x` after you start psql, or you can start psql with it using the `--expanded` flag.

```
\x
Expanded display is on.

test=# SELECT * FROM ( VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6) ) AS t(foo,bar,baz);
-[ RECORD 1 ]
foo | 1
bar | 2
baz | 3
-[ RECORD 2 ]
foo | 4
bar | 5
baz | 6
```

If you're referring to actually knowing where the columns are being sourced from in the display format you can not do that. SQL only maintains a result set. It does not know where the table that originated the data is.

And, that wouldn't make much sense anyway, what would this show...

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT a
  FROM foo
) AS t;
```

Would it show the table as `t` or `a`?

What about this...

```
SELECT a+1 AS b, 'b' AS a
FROM (
  SELECT a
  FROM foo
) AS t;
```

You can see that getting silly really fast.

Answer (score 0):

Will aliases meet your requirement?

```
Select e.empno "emp empno"
,e.sal "emp sal"
,d.deptno "dept deptno"

FROM emp e JOIN dept d ON e.deptno = d.deptno
WHERE e.job = 'Analyst'
```