# Check that a given data is non empty regardless of its data type?

Tags: database, postgresql

In PostgreSQL is there a way we can check that a given data is non empty regardless of its data type. I don't think following will work for all data types:

```
    IF table.columnName IS NOT NULL THEN
    END IF;
```

Comment: For which type do you think that  `is not null` will fail for a `null` value? And what do you mean by 'empty'?

Comment: `is not null` **will** work for all data types.

Comment: `is not null` will work for binary/blob/clob also?

Comment: it will work for **all** datatypes (Postgres has no `clob` or `blob` type though)

Answer (score 1):

`IS NOT NULL` works on all data types.

From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-comparison.html):

> Comparison operators are available for all relevant data types.

Comment: `is not null` will work for binary/geometric/array and all also ??

Comment: If your column is nullable and you've got NULL value, it will be excluded. Simple as that. However, NULL does not mean empty.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a character based column, an empty string IS NOT NULL.

To turn an empty string to NULL you can use: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-nullif/

```
NULLIF(table.columnName, '')
```

Depending on how crazy you want to get in perfection, here are additional resources you can use.

PostgreSQL provides three primary character types: character(n) or char(n), character varying(n) or varchar(n), and text, where n is a positive integer.

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-data-types/

For all other types, "NULL" is the only case when the data type is empty.

To check the type: [How to get a list column names and datatype of a table in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194806/how-to-get-a-list-column-names-and-datatype-of-a-table-in-postgresql)

```
SELECT
    "pg_attribute".attname                                                    as "Column",
    pg_catalog.format_type("pg_attribute".atttypid, "pg_attribute".atttypmod) as "Datatype",

    not("pg_attribute".attnotnull) AS "Nullable"
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_attribute "pg_attribute"
WHERE
    "pg_attribute".attnum > 0
    AND NOT "pg_attribute".attisdropped
    AND "pg_attribute".attrelid = (
        SELECT "pg_class".oid
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_class "pg_class"
            LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace "pg_namespace" ON "pg_namespace".oid = "pg_class".relnamespace
        WHERE
            "pg_namespace".nspname = 'schema'
            AND "pg_class".relname = 'table'
    );
```

You can tweak the above to select only character based types.

To get all the empty strings, here is a function by Erwin that gives all the columns with empty values: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81966/check-whether-empty-strings-are-present-in-character-type-columns

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_empty_status(_tbl regclass, _col colclass)
  RETURNS bool AS
$func$
DECLARE
   -- basic char types, possibly extend with citext, domains or custom types:
   _typ      CONSTANT regtype[] := '{text, bpchar, varchar, "\"char\""}';
   _sql      text;
   _col_arr  text[];
   _null_arr bool[];
BEGIN

-- Build command
SELECT INTO _col_arr, _null_arr, _sql
       array_agg(s.col)
     , array_agg(s.attnotnull)
     , '
SELECT $1
      ,unnest($2)
      ,unnest(ARRAY [count('
              || string_agg(s.col, ' = '''' OR NULL), count(')
                                || ' = '''' OR NULL)])
      ,unnest($3)
FROM   ' || _tbl
FROM  (
   SELECT quote_ident(attname) AS col, attnotnull
   FROM   pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = _tbl              -- valid, visible, legal table name 
   AND    attnum >= 1                  -- exclude tableoid & friends
   AND    NOT attisdropped             -- exclude dropped columns
-- AND    NOT attnotnull               -- include columns defined NOT NULL
   AND    atttypid = ANY(_typ)         -- only character types
   ORDER  BY attnum
   ) AS s;

-- Debug
-- RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;

-- Execute
IF _sql IS NULL THEN
   -- do nothing, nothing to return
ELSE
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE _sql
   USING  _tbl::text, _col_arr, _null_arr;
END IF;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: `For all other types, "NULL" is the only case when the data type is empty` - I'm not sure I'd agree; a zero-element array seems pretty "empty" to me, as does an `'empty'::int4range`, not to mention all the ways you can build a JSON value with nothing in it...

Comment: You are correct, you need to add more cases depending on what you expect to encounter. But if you have JSON, you might consider using MongoDB instead. PostgreSQL is not built for JSON even though it can handle it fine.