# Getting list of column names in a table (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, information-schema

I am trying to get list of column names of a table in postgreSQL via query.
I have searched online for some solutions, but none give expected results.
Here is what I have tried.

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'Accounts';
```

it gives me:

```
Column_name
----------------
character varying
```

What I am looking for is

```
Columns
-------
AccountName
AccountId
Address
ContactPerson
```

Comment: Your code should work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff its not working, do I need to specify DB name somewhere in this query as well ?

Comment: can you verify with following as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194806/how-to-get-a-list-column-names-and-datatype-of-a-table-in-postgresql

Comment: @Addy . . . You can specify the schema.  But your code is returning the type column.  `column_name` should be the column name.  It is unlikely that there is a column named "character varying" anywhere the in the database, but it is, of course, possible.

Comment: Got it adding "table_catalog" worked for me...

Comment: `table_catalog` is meaningless in `information_schema` as all views there will only show information from the current database (=catalog)