# Optimizing MIN / MAX queries on time-series data

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, query-performance, timescaledb

I have several big time-series tables having a lot of Nulls (each table may have up to 300 columns), for example:

**Time-series table**

```
time                |   a     | b        | c       | d
--------------------+---------+----------+---------+---------
2016-05-15 00:08:22 |         |          |         |         
2016-05-15 13:50:56 |         |          | 26.8301 |
2016-05-15 01:41:58 |         |          |         |            
2016-05-15 00:01:37 |         |          |         |            
2016-05-15 01:45:18 |         |          |         |         
2016-05-15 13:45:32 |         |          | 26.9688 |
2016-05-15 00:01:48 |         |          |         |         
2016-05-15 13:47:56 |         |          |         | 27.1269
2016-05-15 00:01:22 |         |          |         |            
2016-05-15 13:35:36 | 26.7441 | 29.8398  |         | 26.9981
2016-05-15 00:08:53 |         |          |         |         
2016-05-15 00:08:30 |         |          |         |         
2016-05-15 13:14:59 |         |          |         |         
2016-05-15 13:33:36 | 27.4277 | 29.7695  |         |                            
2016-05-15 13:36:36 | 27.4688 | 29.6836  |         |            
2016-05-15 13:37:36 | 27.1016 | 29.8516  |         |
```

I want to optimize queries for searching first and last values in every column, i.e.:

```
select MIN(time), MAX(time) from TS where a is not null
```

*(Those queries can run for several minutes)*

I plan to create a metadata table holding column names and pointing to the first and last timestamp:

**Metadata table**

```
col_name | first_time          | last_time
---------+---------------------+--------------------
a        | 2016-05-15 13:35:36 | 2016-05-15 13:37:36
b        | 2016-05-15 13:35:36 | 2016-05-15 13:37:36
c        | 2016-05-15 13:50:56 | 2016-05-15 13:45:32
d        | 2016-05-15 13:47:56 | 2016-05-15 13:35:36
```

This way no Null search will occur during the query and I will just access the value in the first and last timestamps.

But I want to prevent the need to update the metadata table on every time-series data modification. Instead I want to create a generic Trigger Function to which will update `first_time` and `last_time` columns of the metadata table on every Insert, Update or Delete to Time-Series table. The trigger function should compare existing timestamps in the metadata table against inserted / deleted rows.

Any idea if it's possible to create a generic Trigger Function which will not hold the exact column names of time-series table?

Thanks

Comment: Rather try and put indexes on `(a asc, time asc)` and `(a asc, time desc)` (and the same for `b`, `c` and `d`). If you want you can than go for a "metadata" view. Better try to avoid creating redundancy.

Comment: Are you referring a "materialized" view which will be refreshed periodically? I don't see any optimization in a standard view....

Comment: No. Just a "normal" view. The optimization are the indexes.

Comment: I haven't mentioned it initially, but I can have up to 300 columns in TS table. I suspect that having 300 indexes will affect Insert performance more than Trigger functions....

Comment: I also would expect indexes to be slower then trigger because the trigger will only need to update a row when a new min or max value is inserted. While the indexes will need to be updated for every value inserted. BTW you might be tempted to write dynamic code in your trigger that loops over all columns but in my exprience it is better to write a script that generates the trigger with specific code for each column.

Comment: @Eelke, this is exactly what I was thinking and planning. Yet I was thinking about "writing a dynamic code". What exactly do you mean? Create a trigger for each data column and distinguish between trigger calls by "WHEN" (which means if I am inserting values `a` and `b` - 2 different triggers will be called)? Tnx

Comment: No one trigger but write conditions out for each column that test for change in value and then update the metadata when needed. The advantage is that static code is parsed once during creation of the trigger function while dynamic code has to be reparsed on every invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a dynamic query in a trigger function is possible, see this example from [how-to-implement-dynamic-sql-in-postgresql-10](https://hub.packtpub.com/how-to-implement-dynamic-sql-in-postgresql-10/)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION car_portal_app.get_account (predicate TEXT)
RETURNS SETOF car_portal_app.account AS
$$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM car_portal_app.account WHERE ' || predicate;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function is also helpful to build the query string.

You can implement a trigger that fires once per statement (not for every row): the postgres docs have a great example: look at "Example 43.7. Auditing with Transition Tables" in [43.10. Trigger Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-trigger.html)

This will work great for inserts.
But when the min/max of a column is updated/deleted you must check all rows again to find the new min/max. And if this takes several minutes, it should not be done in the trigger.

Comment: Sorry if this was not clear - the question was how to write a trigger function that updates min/max timestamps in a separate table, base on timestamp available in the data to insert / available rows to delete. (and not how to write a generic trigger function).

Comment: @Miro: copied directly from your question: `Any idea if it's possible to create a generic Trigger Function..` :D

Comment: maybe I understood your answer incorrectly or you did..... I don't see any relation between the function you published and the question asked. I am not sure why trigger will run several minutes as it supposed to go over the inserted data only. Yet, "Transition Tables" is an interesting approach.....

Comment: @Miro my answer is only meant to guide you in the right direction, not to provide the exact solution. Using the `format` function, you can build a dynamic query that can do anything. You can get the column names of your tables from the [information_schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194806/how-to-get-a-list-column-names-and-datatype-of-a-table-in-postgresql). The "several minutes" part only refers to update/delete. For inserts it will be okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot with `union all`. I would suggest using a view instead of using a trigger. This has the advantage of being much more flexible, simpler to maintain, and of not slowing down your DML statements:

```
create view metadata_view as
select 'a' col_name, min(time) first_time, max(time) last_time from ts where a is not null
union all select 'b', min(time), max(time) from ts where b is not null
union all select 'c', min(time), max(time) from ts where c is not null
union all select 'd', min(time), max(time) from ts where d is not null
```

For performance, you want the following indexes:

```
ts(a, time)
ts(b, time)
ts(c, time)
ts(d, time)
```

Comment: That `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` in the list of projected columns should better be in `'`s, if I got the OP's intent right. Being as it is, that query should throw an error because they are not in a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I am trying to understand the idea - query like `select 'b', min(time), max(time) from ts where b is not null` can run for several minutes. As far as I understand, having a standard view on top of those queries will not create any optimization when I am trying to find First and Last value quickly.
So you are suggesting to create a materialized view?

Comment: @Miro: ok, you did not initially mentioned that these queries were slow. Before going for a materialized view, please ensure that you have the indexes that I just added to my answer.

Comment: @Miro And: before worrying about performance, maybe reconsider your database-design?

Comment: What if I have 300 columns? Are you sure that insert performance will still be reasonable with 300 indexes? I am working with Time-Series data, so I am not sure how to reconsider DB design.....

Comment: @Miro: do you really have 300 columns? Anyway, I think that there is no generic answer to your question, you would need to go and test it...

Comment: When it comes to database design I suppose that @wildplasser meant: split your table into different tables, once per existing `a, b, ...` column so you can avoid these gaps in your dataset.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do have those numbers (sorry for not mentioning it initially). Putting those in different tables is also not an option, because the data is queried (and aggregated) together and having a lot of joins is not a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to do this using multiple columns:

```
select min(time) filter (where a is not null) as a_min,
       max(time) filter (where a is not null) as a_max,
       min(time) filter (where b is not null) as b_min,
       max(time) filter (where b is not null) as b_max,
       min(time) filter (where c is not null) as c_min,
       max(time) filter (where c is not null) as c_max,
       min(time) filter (where d is not null) as d_min,
       max(time) filter (where d is not null) as d_max,    
from t;
```

You can then unpivot after this step:

```
select v.*
from (select min(time) filter (where a is not null) as a_min,
             max(time) filter (where a is not null) as a_max,
             min(time) filter (where b is not null) as b_min,
             max(time) filter (where b is not null) as b_max,
             min(time) filter (where c is not null) as c_min,
             max(time) filter (where c is not null) as c_max,
             min(time) filter (where d is not null) as d_min,
             max(time) filter (where d is not null) as d_max,    
      from metadata
     ) x cross join lateral
     (values ('a', min_a, max_a),
             ('b', min_b, max_b),
             ('c', min_c, max_c),
             ('d', min_d, max_d)
     ) v(which, min_val, max_val);
```

Instead of creating a trigger, I would opt for indexes, which can be used with GMB's approach.

Comment: Maybe even create partial indices?

Comment: What do you mean by partial indices in this case? Thanks

Comment: @Miro . . . I think indexes on the `time` column where each of the other four columns are `NULL` (four separate indexes).