# identify PostgreSQL data types

Tags: postgresql

I usually use MySQL, to determine its data type, I use 'describe column_name;' but in PostgreSQL, it doesn't work. What is the correct formula to determine data types in PostgreSQL?

I tried inputting the code:
describe column_name;
\d table_name;
but none of them worked

Comment: `\d` only works in the `psql` shell

Comment: if you have custom types, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58319308/7635569)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would query the view `information_schema.columns`, which should work on all standard compliant databases:

```
SELECT data_type, numeric_precision, numeric_scale, character_maximum_length
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'schemaname'
  AND table_name = 'tablename'
  AND column_name = 'columnname';
```

`numeric_precision`, `numeric_scale` and `character_maximum_length` are the optional type modifiers for the respective data types.