# Is there a way to see the type of a SQL expression?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I select a SQL expression:

```
my_db=> select cast('2019-12-12' as date) + cast('10:00' as time);
      ?column?       
---------------------
 2019-12-12 10:00:00
(1 row)
```

Is there a way for me to view what type that column is? E.g. is it a `timestamp with time zone` or a `timestamp without time zone;`.

So ideally something like:

```
my_db=> select type(cast('2019-12-12' as date) + cast('10:00' as time));
          ?column?       
-----------------------------
 timestamp without time zone
(1 row)
```

It may be that my example works only in postgresql, but I'd like to know if there is a standard SQL way of doing it, and if not if there's a postgresql way of doing it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53964639/5070879 - \gdesc

Comment: `standard SQL way of doing it` I doubt you will find a general way to describe result set. One workaround may be creating view/table based on query and read INFROMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS but it is ugly solution. SQL Server has [dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql)

Comment: Amazing, thanks @LukaszSzozda

Comment: Why not simply use `Desc` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pg_typeof(<expression>)` in Postgresql.

So for your example:

```
my_db=> select pg_typeof(cast('2019-12-12' as date) + cast('10:00' as time));
          pg_typeof          
-----------------------------
 timestamp without time zone
(1 row)
```